# Reading Pandas Data frame if condition occurs in any row/column

Tags: pandas

Attempting to read a data frame that has values in a random rows/columns order and I would like to get a new column where the all the values containing 'that' are summarized.

```
Input:
    0       1       2       3       4
0   this=1  that=2  who=2   was=3   where=5
1   that=4  who=5   this=1  was=3   where=2
2   was=2   who=7   this=7  that=3  where=7
3   was=3   who=4   this=7  that=1  where=8
4   that=1  who=3   this=4  was=1   where=3


Output:
    0
0   that=2
1   that=4
2   that=3
3   that=1
4   that=1
```

I have been successfully able to get the correct result with the following code. But with larger data frames it takes a long time to complete

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([['this=1', 'that=2', 'who=2', 'was=3', 'where=5'],
                 ['that=4', 'who=5', 'this=1', 'was=3', 'where=2'],
                 ['was=2', 'who=7', 'this=7', 'that=3','where=7'],
                 ['was=3', 'who=4', 'this=7', 'that=1', 'where=8'],
                 ['that=1', 'who=3', 'this=4', 'was=1', 'where=3']], 
                columns=[0,1,2,3,4])

df2=pd.DataFrame()
for i in df1.index:
    data=[name for name in df1[i] if name[0:4]=='that']
    df2=df2.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Comment: shouldn't `that=2` exist? column `1` and index `0`?

Comment: [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('that'))].stack()
```

Let's break this down:

`df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('that'))` Applies our `lambda` function to the entire dataframe. in english it reads: if `that` is in our value, `True`

```
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False   True  False  False  False
1   True  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False   True  False
3  False  False  False   True  False
4   True  False  False  False  False
```

`df1[]` around that will return the values, instead of `True`/`False`:

```
        0       1    2       3    4
0     NaN  that=2  NaN     NaN  NaN
1  that=4     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
2     NaN     NaN  NaN  that=3  NaN
3     NaN     NaN  NaN  that=1  NaN
4  that=1     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
```

[`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) will *stack* all the values into one Series. `stack()` gets rid of `NA` by default, which is what you needed.

if the extra index is tripping you up, you can also reset the index for a single series:

```
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('that'))].stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0    that=2
1    that=4
2    that=3
3    that=1
4    that=1
dtype: object
```

Comment: Great answer with perfect analysis. A+